# Type mismatch Can't assign task.Task to x.Interface1

Tags: java, hibernate, generics

I created an abstract class like below:

```
public abstract class AbstractObjectRemover< O extends Interface1 & Interface2<Long>,
    N extends Interface1 & Interface2<Long>
{

    public void deleteObjects( List< O > aOldObjects, List< N > aNewObjects ) {

    }

    public void deleteSingleObject ( N aNewObject ) {
       // code
    }
}
```

My purpose is to force that the class passed in generic must implement both interfaces: Interface1 and Interface2.
Then I created a simple extension of that abstract remover

```
public class DeleteTaskProcessor extends AbstractObjectRemover<TaskOld, Task> implements SynchronizationProcessorIf< Task >
{
    private List<Task> taskToDelete;

    private final TaskOldRepositoryExtIf taskOldRepository;
    private final TaskRepositoryExtIf taskRepository;

    @Inject
    public DeleteTaskProcessor( TaskOldRepositoryExtIf aTaskOldRepository,
                                TaskRepositoryExtIf aTaskRepository )
    {
        taskOldRepository = aTaskOldRepository;
        taskRepository = aTaskRepository;
        taskToDelete = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void process()
    {
        taskToDelete.forEach( this::deleteSingleObject );
    }

    @Override
    public void setObjectList( List< Task > aObjectList )
    {
        this.taskToDelete = aObjectList;
    }
}
```

When i call the `process` method ther is an error

> Type mismatch Can't assign task.Task to
> x.Interface1

What am i doing wrong?